# Can every Lie group be realized as conformal group of smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, conformal-geometry

I was reading a paper

*Saerens, Rita; Zame, William R.*, [**The isometry groups of manifolds and the automorphism groups of domains**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2000347), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 301, 413-429 (1987). [ZBL0621.32025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0621.32025).

Here they showed,

> We prove that every compact Lie group can be realized as the
> (full) automorphism group of a strictly pseudoconvex domain and as the (full)
> *isometry* group of a compact, connected, smooth Riemannian manifold.

Now my question is:

Are their any papers or theorems which shows that every lie group can also be realized as the full **[Conformal Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_group#Mathematical_definition)** of some smooth manifold.

Comment: There's specific cases, not general results.

Comment: @rumathe So can you please give me such references what you are saying about

Comment: @DeponjitBose Sorry, I am not specialist in the field, but I'll do my best

Comment: @rumathe Thanks man, I'll be waiting for your response.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, one cannot talk about conformal transformations of a smooth manifold: For the notion of conformality to be defined you need an extra structure besides a smooth atlas. I will work with the notion of conformality in Riemannian geometry.

**Definition.**  Suppose that $(,ℎ)$ is a connected Riemannian manifold and $=\operatorname{Conf}(,ℎ)$, the full group of conformal automorphisms of $(,ℎ)$. The group $G$ is called **inessential** if there is a positive function $\rho$ on $M$ such that the group $G$ acts isometrically on the Riemannian manifold $(M, \rho h)$.

Lichnerowicz's conjectured and Ferrand proved in

*Ferrand, Jacqueline*, [**The action of conformal transformations on a Riemannian manifold**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01446294), Math. Ann. 304, No. 2, 277-291 (1996). [ZBL0866.53027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0866.53027).

that apart from the Riemannian manifolds conformal to the Euclidean space (with the flat metric) and the round sphere, all Riemannian manifolds have inessential groups of conformal transformations. Thus, apart from the two exceptions, the story reduces to the realization of the given noncompact Lie group as the full isometry group of a Riemannian manifold. However, it appears that this question is still unanswered, see an incomplete Mathoverflow discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87070/can-every-lie-group-be-realized-as-the-full-isometry-group-of-a-riemannian-manif).

Comment: The statement which you have said does it also hold for Sem-Riemannian Manifold with degenerate metric?

Comment: @DeeponjitBose: Ferrand's result is only for the Riemannian case. I do not think there is a general theorem in the semi-Riemannian case.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for your response, probably in the future someone will discover a general theorem regarding Semi-Riemannian Manifolds even with degenerate metric

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in comments, I am not very knowledgable in this field. As far as I know the conformal group of a smooth manifold has been studied extensively in various contexts, and some specific cases are known.

1. Conformal group of n-dimensional Euclidean space:
   [Lee, J. M. (2006). Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ejchaidez/materials/reu/lee_smooth_manifolds.pdf)
2. Conformal group of Minkowski space and Anti-de Sitter space:
   [Fulton, T., Rohrlich, F., & Witten, L. (1962). Conformal Invariance in Physics](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.34.442)
   [Bekaert, X., & Boulanger, N. (2006). The unitary representations of the Poincaré group in any spacetime dimension](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0611263)
   [Barut, A. O., & Raczka, R. (1980). Theory of Group Representations and Applications](https://github.com/carlosal1015/Books/blob/master/Physics/A.%20O%20Barut%20Theory%20of%20group%20representations%20and%20applications%20part%201.pdf)
   [Avis, S. J., Isham, C. J., & Storey, D. (1978). Quantum field theory in anti-de Sitter space-time](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.18.3565)
3. Conformal groups of compact, simply connected, and positively curved Riemannian manifolds:
   [Obata, M. (1971). The conjectures on conformal transformations of Riemannian manifolds](https://projecteuclid.org/accountAjax/Download?downloadType=Journal%20Article&urlId=10.4310%2Fjdg%2F1214430407&isResultClick=True)
   [Ejiri, N. (1981). A negative answer to a conjecture of conformal transformations of Riemannian manifolds](https://projecteuclid.org/accountAjax/Download?downloadType=Journal%20Article&urlId=10.2969%2Fjmsj%2F03320261&isResultClick=True)
   [Gursky, M. J., & Viaclovsky, J. A. (2001). A new variational characterization of three-dimensional space forms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227189627_A_new_variational_characterization_of_three-dimensional_space_forms)